# Possible is to download the file vdo from url to iPad? - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I want to create player on mobile.

Possible is to download the file vdo from url to iPad and set filename  of player to file it for play vdo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if "vdo" refers to somethin specific. Normally, you can download any file with

```
put "binfile:" & specialfolderpath("documents") & "/somefilename.vdo" into myPath
put "http://www.somedomain.xyz/somefilename.vdo" into myUrl
put url myUrl into url myPath
```

From then on, you can access the file `specialfolderpath("documents") & "/somefilename.vdo"`without internet connection.